# Polymorphism whilst using boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, polymorphism, overriding

If I have an inheritance hierarchy with parent class A and child classes B and C how can I use polymorphism via boost::shared_ptr<> so that a function

```
virtual void my_func(boost::shared_ptr<A> x) = 0;
```

can be implemented as

```
void my_func(boost::shared_ptr<B> x);
```

and

```
void my_func(boost::shared_ptr<C> x);
```

? Does the polymorphism still work even though there's the shared_ptr concept?

(Would be good to know if this works for the std::shared_ptr as well as boost)

Comment: These function signatures are not equivalent. So I don't think you are exactly overriding here.

Answer (score 1):

When overriding functions in C++ the argument types have to be identical to those in the base class. The only variation allowed is that the overriding function may have a covariant return type if the base class returns a pointer or a reference.

For argument types any potential variation would depend on what kind of argument it is:

- Input arguments need to be contravariant: you can allow passing in more general arguments if you know that your more special class can deal with them.
- Output arguments need to be covariant: any call can cope with objects of the base type, i.e., it is OK to get something more special when the class is know to be special.
- C++ doesn't have an indication if input or output parameters, i.e., the parameters are always input and output parameters. Thus, they are invariant.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the first point: why input args could be *contravariant*? Why not covariant as in case of output/retval?

Comment: @IgorR.: That input arguments have to be contravariant immediately derives from the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP): if `base.f(x)` can be called, `derived.f(x)` has to be callable. When `derived` restricts `x` to be a derived class compared to that used by `base` it is clear that `derived.f(x)` can't be called with all inputs `base.f(x)` can be and you have a LSP violation.